# Problems with a MySQL server change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE  `mlm`.`facturacion_2012_drm_base` (   `custid`
varchar(20) NOT NULL,   `fecha` date NOT NULL,   `docid` varchar(20)
NOT NULL,   `billid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,   `movimiento` varchar(20)
DEFAULT NULL,   `movid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,   `medio_pago`
varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,   `digitos` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
`monto_facturado` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,   `monto_pagado`
decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,   `monto_usado` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,  
`documento` varchar(2) NOT NULL,   `codigo_pago` varchar(5) DEFAULT
NULL,   `desc_pago` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   `sociedad`
varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `sociedad_bonif` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `billid` (`billid`),   KEY `motors_no_fact`
(`custid`,`billid`,`fecha`,`documento`) USING BTREE,   KEY
`facturacion` (`custid`,`fecha`,`documento`) USING BTREE )
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE  `mlm`.`facturacion_2012_drm_cortes` (   `id` bigint(20)
NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `fecha_inicial` date NOT NULL,  
`fecha_final` date NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=433 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE  `mlm`.`facturacion_2012_drm_emitidas` (   `id`
bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `custid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
`fecha_emision` date NOT NULL,   `id_fechas` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
`monto` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,   `iva` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,  
`total` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,   `medio_pago` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
`digitos` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `operaciones` int(10) NOT NULL,  
`activa` varchar(2) NOT NULL,   `movimiento` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
`parcialidades` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `monto_bruto` decimal(20,2)
NOT NULL,   `billid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,   `serie` varchar(2)
DEFAULT NULL,   `folio` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,   `uuid` varchar(45)
DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   KEY `motors`
(`billid`,`id_fechas`,`activa`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=511483
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I changed the MySQL server from 5.1 (32 Bits) to 5.6 (64 Bits) and restored all my tables but I´m having problems with this query:

```
SELECT a.custid, 
       a.monto_facturado, 
       a.billid, 
       a.fecha, 
       b.id, 
       b.fecha_inicial 
FROM   facturacion_2012_drm_base a, 
       facturacion_2012_drm_cortes b 
WHERE  a.custid = ANY (SELECT custid 
                       FROM   facturacion_motors_pendientes 
                       WHERE  situacion = 'no facturado') 
       AND a.billid <> ALL (SELECT billid 
                            FROM   facturacion_2012_drm_emitidas 
                            WHERE  activa = 'SI') 
       AND a.fecha BETWEEN b.fecha_inicial AND b.fecha_final 
       AND a.documento = 'FA' 
       AND Year(a.fecha) = Year(Curdate()) 
GROUP  BY a.billid
```

Since the server change, the query never finish, showing the message "Query is being executed..."

Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` before your statement and run, then post the results.

Comment: Hi, this is the result: "id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
1,"PRIMARY","facturacion_motors_pendientes","ALL","","","","",5,"Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary"
1,"PRIMARY","b","ALL","","","","",424,"Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
1,"PRIMARY","a","ALL","motors_no_fact,facturacion","","","",3875388,"Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6); End temporary"
3,"SUBQUERY","facturacion_2012_drm_emitidas","index","motors","motors","59","",419111,"Using where; Using index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least you have indexing problems:

- On `facturacion_2012_drm_emitidas` you filter by `activa` but do not have an index that can be used for this
- On `facturacion_2012_drm_base` you don't have an index for `fecha` or `documento` that can be used
- On `facturacion_2012_drm_cortes` you don't have an index for `fecha_inicial` or `fecha_final`
- I don't know if you have index problems on `facturacion_motors_pendientes` because you did not include DDL for it.

Make sure you have the proper indexes for your query and then see what happens. What is happening now is that you have a complex join with subqueries and basically none of it is utilizing indexes, requiring you to execute full table scans on all tables involved.

You also might consider converting these tables to InnoDB, as that is the preferred table type in 5.6.  This is of course unless you need certain MyISAM functionality on these tables (like full text search).

Comment: Thanks Mike, in the fourth table involved (facturacion_motors_pendientes) I had custid in "BIGINT(20)" instead of "VARCHAR(20)", so that was the reason MySQL didn't use the index.

Comment: @Jaymz Not sure about the 4th table, but MYSQL wouldn't have been using a a lot of other things you are doing in your query, as there either weren't indexes in place, or the columns were part of a compound index, but were not the first index in the compound index such that the index wouldn't be used. I just mention this as there is certainly more than one index that needs to be fixed/added to make this query run efficiently.